# GraphQLSchema bean not created - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I am following this example here:- http://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql

for me the GraphQLSchema bean is not getting autoregistered. it throws me this error:-
No qualifying bean of type 'graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema' available

my Pom file has all requried Spring boot dependecies:-

```
graphql-spring-boot-starter
graphql-java-tools
graphiql-spring-boot-starter
```

I have following settings in application.proerties:-

```
graphql.root=/v1
graphql.servlet.mapping=${graphql.root}/graphql
graphql.servlet.enabled=true
graphql.servlet.corsEnabled=true
```

Not sure what am I missing, Do I need to explicitly define this bean as on this page:- https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/embedler/moon/graphql/boot/sample/ApplicationBootConfiguration.java.

But I thought it will autocreate for me, I just need to have *.graphqls on my class path.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the same tutorial as well and encountered the same error. I ended up figuring out what the issue was and it is that you need to add `@Component` to the `Query` class that the tutorial describes.

Once that was done `graphiql` was finally finding the schema and the `/graphql` end-point was exposed.